# Wrong calculation in SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server

As an example I found a simple calculation like:

```
select cast(200.00 as float) + 1908.30 + 170.00 + (-1150.00) + (-1128.30)
```

As a normal addition this results in `0.00` but SQL Server shows the result as `2.27373675443232E-13`.

Why is this and how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error is inherent in the `float` datatype, and is the reason for the existence of `decimal` type. Never do money calculations as `float` values!

You can take a look at [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), or any Google result for "float rounding error".

Comment: Changing `float` to `real` (which is a 'lighter', i.e. lower precision variance of `float`) in the OP's example results in the output of `0`. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast(200.00 as decimal(10,2)) + 1908.30 + 170.00 + (-1150.00) + (-1128.30)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not unique to sql.
For example, in python:

```
'%.50f' % (200.+1908.3+170.-1150.-1128.30)
```

Will result in

```
'0.00000000000022737367544323205947875976562500000000'
```

Which is the same you got.

This is inherent to the inability to represent every number that can be expressed as a finite sum of powers of 10 (such as 1908.3) as a finite sum of positive and negative powers of 2, which is what representing it as a float does.  An inevitable approximation occurs, and as you perform operations on said approximations, the final result may have a small error.  The link provided by Amadan explains it.