# Large scale decimal computation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, decimal, sql-server-2016

I've got stuck on some mathematical action that I perform in SQL Server 2016 Enterprise.

I need to calculate this expression:

```
(4.384 / 4.2989 * 100) * 98.8251017928029 / 100
```

In SQL I get the result `100.78141988869389772850690000`

But when I calculate this expression in MS Excel, I get: `100.7814199585120000`

Since these results is a Consumer Price index, the numbers after the decimal point do matter.

So, my question is, which result is correct? SQL Server or Excel.

PS. I have updated my question.
Here is [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=35c5ad4d044567fc21fcf8c3eaffc3eb)

Thank you.

Comment: Excel has a 15 significant digit limit due to floating point calculation. Lots on the interweb to read about it.

Comment: So, if I cast all my decimal to float, I should receive the same result as in Excel?

Comment: To lock down a 15 significant digit result in MS SQL you should probably use either Decimal or Numeric where you can specify both precision and scale.

Comment: `FLOAT` in SQL Server is notoriously susceptible to rounding errors - if you want precise calculations, use `DECIMAL(p,s)` instead

Comment: I do, i use decimals in my sql expressions, but the result is different from excel.

Comment: do you really required that many decimals ?

Comment: Yes, I do. This is Price index in regions, and the official statistic is based on this numbers

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem here: [Wrong calculation in SQL-Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815884/wrong-calculation-in-sql-server)
I've also tried the calculation with java, and it shows the result of the excel is more accurate.
You should use decimal in calculation using sql.

Comment: that is `float` data type. as stated in documentation it is `Approximate-number data types`. By the way, this is not an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, creating DbFiddle I found errors in cast. So when errors was fixed the result now the are almost the same as in excel. There is small difference in results but the difference is behind my needs of scale

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT (CONVERT(FLOAT,4.384) / CONVERT(FLOAT,4.2989) * CONVERT(FLOAT,100)) * CONVERT(FLOAT,98.8251017928029) / CONVERT(FLOAT,100)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.